# SSH Proxy vs VPN Killswitch

Tags: vpn, ssh, proxy, openvpn, openssh

This might be complete nonsense but I've heard people talking about so I'm interested to see if it's valid: I've heard people saying that SOCKS and SSH are more secure/private than a VPN because they rigorously enforce a killswitch if the SSH connection drops (whereas, by default, if a VPN connection fails, the computer starts to direct traffic in the clear). Is this valid and, if so, are there servicrs that provide this (similar to a VPN service), is there away to strictly enforce all traffic to be routed through this SSH SOCKS proxy tunnel, and is there a way to set this up that also prevents DNS leaks?

Sorry if this makes no sense, and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to enforce all traffic via socks proxy. You would be better with VPN.

You can configure system to not connect to the internet if not on VPN connection, Linux for example has such tickerbox to enable it without hassle. It can also be done using firewall and routing. It depends on what OS you are using and what VPN.

Using routing for example, you configure only routing to your VPN router and do not configure default gateway. This way, default gateway is setup only on VPN connection. Also to prevent DNS leaks, you configure DNS to 8.8.8.8 so it works only via VPN default gateway. In this simple way you can do it with VPN.